# How robust are multivariate methods to violations of normality?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, normality-assumption, robust

In many cases, multivariate methods are used without normality tests.
How are following methods robust if data are not normal?

- Principal components analysis
- Canonical correlations analysis
- Factor analysis
- Multivariate regression analysis
- Multivariate analysis of variance
- Discriminant analysis

Comment: This question should be split into 6 distinct questions.

Comment: Is it possible and correct? I think that is is better for users to have it all in one question.

Comment: I believe that every point deserves a full and complete answer. I also see, that the methods you mention have very little in common. Putting it as a one question suggest you expect one answer. You would hardly get one, since it would require a lot of expertise and it will be very long one too.

Comment: No, I know that there does not exist the same answer for all methods. Some are more and some are less robust, and as you mentioned, PCA and FA do not assume normality, so robustness to its violation is meaningless.

Comment: I agree with @AdamRyczkowski. This is at least 6 questions!

Comment: The subject matter is good, but there are three to four distinct subjects here: PCA/FA, regression/ANOVA, and discriminant analysis (canonical correlations could be discussed by itself or perhaps under PCA or regression, I believe). Closing this question is *not* prejudicial, but only a necessary first step to refining it so it is not too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1):

**Ad Principal components analysis and Factor analysis:**

These methods are only exploratory and they never assume normality. They are non-stable (i.e. sensitive to small random variations of input data) when there are pairs of very similar eigenvalues, especially when the elements of the pair have relatively large value.

**Ad Multivariate regression analysis, canonical correlation, MANOVA**

Distribution of covariance matrix is sensitive to kurtosis of the sample, so if you have data with adjusted kurtosis different from 0, this method will give wrong p-values (*see van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics", p. 28, Cambridge Univ. Press, 2000*)

I can even say, that the distribution of covariance matrix is sensitive *only* to kurtosis of the sample and, in less degree, every other even moment of the distribution, but in descending power (i.e. the higher is the moment which is different from normal distribution, the less influence it has on distribution of the covariance matrix).